# I want to start listening to Electronic, trance and house music, where and how should I start?

Tags: genre

I want to start listening to electronic, house, and trance music. Where should I start? What artists should I listen to? Please help me.

Comment: Do you want a holistic tour of electronic music, or are you mainly just interested in the house and trance area?

Comment: Yes, I want a holistic tour of electronic music. (I tried to find a documentary about electronic music or such things that talk about different types and bands and songs of electronic music but I didn't find anything useful.)

Comment: Venetian Snares. Most of his albums are good, the "Cavalcade of Glee..." is one of my faves.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is nearly impossible to give a concise or specific answer, as it'll depend a lot on your tastes and/or your goals. Without knowing that, here's how I'd go (...and have gone) about it.

First, go here -- http://techno.org/electronic-music-guide/ -- and click around. Seriously. Listen to the sample, read his descriptions. This will give you a sense of how the different microgenres relate to one another, both stylistically and temporally. Since this site also provides samples for every (I think) microgenre, you should also be able to find a few bands to your liking to help direct your path.

(Do note that this site, while extensive and overall pretty great, is not without its faults. In particular, the author appears fairly opinionated and may have biases. Additionally, while the samples are *representative*, they are not necessarily the *best* or, especially, the most well known.)

Second, pick up the "consensus" picks for best in genre. You can google things like "best electronica albums" and see some lists -- [this NME list](http://www.nme.com/photos/40-albums-that-changed-dance-music-forever/342912) looks pretty decent -- but I'd just go to [Acclaimed Music's](http://acclaimedmusic.net/) consolidation of lists and pull up their genre-specific rankings. They do break them out somewhat based on subgenre. (Due to their site design, I can't link directly, but click the "genre" link in the header.)

At this point, you should begin to see how things fit together, what People generally consider the best, and have an idea of what/who you like. Then, it's just a matter of digging deeper.

Comment: Knowing my answer doesn't have any specifics, here are a few albums that I personally like that generally show up on "best of" lists: The Orb - Adventure's Beyond the Ultraworld; Aphex Twin - Selected Ambient Works II; Chemical Brothers - Dig Your Own Hole; 808 State - 90.

Answer (score 1):

Search for **God's trance compilation**  this was a legendary youtube channel untill most videos were deleted because of copyright issues. Though you can still find many Trance mixes  on Youtube. Go for `progressive and uplifting melodic trance`.

There are tons of trance music produced every day there is a weekly prodcast **[A State of Trance](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitlPbhh8DMAhXK1I4KHdAbCBsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fastateoftrance&usg=AFQjCNETTmv_S0Ro3u-5fZbl_EZ02qSgvQ&sig2=_DgxuMHiaqjZlKGIU3jCrg)** I used to hear it in college days but nowdays most music are repetitive and sound similar. Worth a shot anyways.

> Most important part of  listening music is you need to keep on
>   exploring as we exploit a song we like so much that we end up hating
>   it and then we need to find something new to replace it.

you can find amazing and unrated tracks on **Soundcloud.**